# How can I find out if a virsh VM has qcow storage attached as non persistent?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virsh

I have multiple (KVM) VM's being managed under virsh in different servers (ubuntu precise and up). I need to check if any of those have qcow disks attached non persistently.

Was hoping for something like this to help me out:

```
virsh domblklist domain --details
```

Is there something similar that can provide information on the storage attachment method?

**edit:** (not 100% sure) I could do an xml dump and then grep for the contents of the aforementioned command for each VM. If I cannot find the content in the domain's xml then I could assume that it is set as non persistent.. I dislike this method and would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `virsh domblklist domain --inactive --details`

From [virsh man page:](https://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh)

> **domblklist domain [--inactive] [--details]** Print a table showing the
>   brief information of all block devices associated with domain. If
>   --inactive is specified, query the block devices that will be used on the next boot, rather than those currently in use by a running domain.
>   If --details is specified, disk type and device value will also be
>   printed. Other contexts that require a block device name (such as
>   domblkinfo or snapshot-create for disk snapshots) will accept either
>   target or unique source names printed by this command.

Comment: I ended up doing this:
`for vm in \`virsh list | tail -n +3 | awk '{ print $2}'\`; do echo $vm; vcompare1=$(virsh domblklist $vm --inactive  | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1}' ); vcompare2=$(virsh domblklist $vm  | tail -n +3 | awk '{ print $1}'); for i in \`echo $vcompare2\`; do grep -v $i <(echo $vcompare1) 2>&1 1>/dev/null && echo -e "\tfound: $i $(virsh domblklist $vm --inactive  | grep $i)"; done; done`
For some reason the $() inside the echo didn't always work, not sure why. --details was not necessary and incompatible with some virsh versions.